# about misfire in java quartz scheduling

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have set a trigger using `cronScheduler` with `misfireInstruction` like follows

```
     trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity("autoLockTrigger", "autoLockGroup").startNow()                 .withSchedule(cronSchedule(croneExpression).withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed())
                    .forJob("autoLockJob","autoLockGroup")
                    .build();
```

my quartz.properties is like follows

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName =MyScheduler


# Configuring ThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 1
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 9

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS 
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
#org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.jndiURL = jdbc/vikas


org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = jdbc:mysql://staging:3307/facao
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user = root
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password = toor
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 30


#org.quartz.jobStore.nonManagedTXDataSource = myDS
#to store data in string format (name-value pair)
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=true   

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
```

In my code if I set some trigger at particular time and if server is in running state then scheduler runs properly but if server is down for the time in which scheduler is suppose to be run and then started after some time then scheduler should run the misfired instruction. But in my case the misfired instruction is not running all the time it runs some time not always so my purpose is not fulfilled. Please give some solution. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the cron triggers but for simple triggers yeah, 
if the end time of the trigger has been passed then some of the provided misfire instruction 
will not work. See the [javadoc](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/SimpleTrigger.html#MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_RESCHEDULE_NEXT_WITH_REMAINING_COUNT) snippet for more info.
I guess the same would be the case with cron trigger too.
So, it totally depends on what cron expression you use.

Comment: do you know any reason for this? Is there any threading problem or is there any setting in quartz.properties which is missing? I said threading problem because it runs sometimes and fails sometimes. So some thread with higher priority may be running. So it may have stop working.

Comment: will be nice if you provide your cron expression here :-)

Comment: i am dynamically generating crone expression. Latest was this one     "0 14 12 6 6  ?" on which i tested the scheduler. I just down the server and after 15 minutes restarted it. but misfire instruction is not fired.